# OPEN statement with status="old" creates a new file and hangs

Tags: fortran, fortran77

Having trouble with file processing in some old FORTRAN 77 code im dissecting. The sample code is below:

```
      WRITE(*,15)
15    FORMAT(' INPUT NAME OF DATA FILE TO BE USED AS INPUT ')
      READ(*,10)BDFILE
10    FORMAT(A10)
      OPEN(UNIT=2,ERR=999,FILE=BDFILE,STATUS='OLD',IOSTAT=IOS)
      REWIND 2
```

The problem is with the OPEN statement. Despite having STATUS='OLD', the statement is making a new, blank file that wipes out the existing file-- then it just hangs theres.

This is from code that must have worked in the past, so im a bit confused as to why its broken now. 
One of my guesses is the compiler i'm using? I wasn't able to find any of the ancient F77 compilers, only modern legacy compatible ones. I compiled this with FTN95.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: Which exact compiler do you use? Which options? We will need more code, see [mcve]. We will also need more information about your operating system.

Comment: This is essentially all the code up until it hangs. I believe it is a compiler compatibility issue, as i just found a 20+ year old one that makes a workable program. Found a similiar situation on stack overflow that was never resolved, hopefully people finding this now will have a better idea of how they might fix it.

Comment: If it is a compiler compatibility issue then I repeat that we need your details about the compiler version and options  and your operating system. See [mcve] and [ask]. A real MWE is not *essentially*, it is a real piece of code one can compile and try. Compiler bugs often depend on minuscule details.

Comment: Please don't use `unit=2` (and `rewind 2`) use a unit number > 10 as the lower numbers might be used by the system ()compiler dependent!) for other tasks (e.g., in C terms, stdin / stdout / stderr)